# using 再想像 or 再創造 for reimagined?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances, usage

I'm trying to decide between 再創造 and 再想像 for reimagined, specifically in the context of a "reimagined story", like 再創造された物語。

I'm leaning toward 創造 because, to my understanding, 創造 refers to creating something new from something pre-existing, but 想像する literally means "to imagine" so I'm unsure which to go with. Or would there be a better way of saying "reimagined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再想像, on a literal sense, is re-imagine, but more like to imagine(conjure up an image) again.

再創造, on the other hand, is re-create, and has the same shade of meaning as the English word recreate, or to create over again.

The problem is that with the English phrase “a story reimagined”, it’s referring to that, based on an existing story, you changed something to make a new story out of it. Such practice in Japanese is better described as 二次創作, or 再創作 if you wish, because instead of 創造 or 想像, 創作 is the proper term for when you write a story or produce music. The term itself should translate to “produce”.

Here is a Wiki entry for 二次創作

https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E6%AC%A1%E5%89%B5%E4%BD%9C